# Doubt regarding convergence!

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $f_{n} \to f$ in measure & that there exists a $g \in L^1$ such that $|f_{n}| \le g $ a.e. $\forall $  $n$ . Then, show that: $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ $ \int_{X} |f_{n} - f| \, d\mu$ $ = 0 $.

My Thought :

$|f_{n} - f| \le |f_{n}| + |f| \le g + |f|$ . Observing this, my strategy was to use Dominated Convergence Theorem. But, what is the assurance that $|f| \in L^{1}$ ?? So..any solution??

Answer (score 0):

You have $|f_n|\leq g$ a.e. so that implies $|f|\leq g$ a.e. So clearly $f\in L^1$ if $g\in L^1$.

To show the first claim, $\{f-g>\epsilon\}=\{f-f_n+f_n-g>\epsilon\}$, so the event $\{f-g>\epsilon\}$ implies $\{f-f_n>\epsilon/2\}\cup\{f_n-g>\epsilon/2\}$. Hence,

$$\mu(f-g>\epsilon)\leq \mu(f-f_n>\epsilon/2)+\mu(f_n-g>\epsilon/2).$$

Clearly $\mu(f_n-g>\epsilon/2)=0$, and $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure so $\mu(f-f_n>\epsilon/2)$ goes to 0 and the left-hand-side is independent of $n$.

Comment: From $|f_{n}| \le g$ a.e. & $f_{n} \to f$ in measure. From that how can you conclude $|f| \le g$ a.e. ??

Comment: @user92360: try proving it by contradiction. A simpler example to keep in mind is that if $a_n$ is a sequence of numbers with limit $a$ and if $a_n\leq b$ then $a\leq b$.

Comment: The simpler example that you provided is fine... but in the problem proving it by contradiction how to tackle the issue that $f_{n} \to f$ in measure??

Comment: @user92360: I've sketched it out in the answer.

Comment: Yes! Yes!..sorry for the late reply!!.... I got it!! :)